# What is the best way to create a wallpaper app for android?

Tags: android, picasa, google-photos-api

I am sure you are fine and happy. I want to create a wallpaper app for android. I am a newbie to be honest.

- There used to be picasaweb and its api for storing albums and fetching images on an android application. This api is discontinued now. I searched for online tutorials. Almost all of the tutorials used this old api. Some of the tutorials were there, which were only using drawable folder images to set the wallpaper, which i do not want. I want to create an application where users can download wallpapers from my online storage. I found that there is now a google photos api. There is a good documentation of it. But i don't honestly know how to implement it in my app. I am a bit puzzled now.

My main question is, how should i proceed to create my app. It may sound a bit spoon feeding, but what is the best way to create this type of app. I know i will need to store images on a storage and will need to create an api to download and fetch image data on the storage. (Is there any good api available already, like volley?) Also, somewhere i found that i can use firebase storage, but i have read in both firebase and google photos api, there is a limit in the amount of access request users can make in a day. There is a partner program also. which increase these storage and request cap.

Also if the question is in a bad format, please forgive me this time, I'll be more specific next time. I'll be very thankful for any hints and help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For starting the android project, you can start by learning the Java programming language. Then you can following learning the [basic android development](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgCF58tuo2k&list=PLshdtb5UWjSrOJfpFOE-u55s3SnY2EO9v). After basic, you can follow the [Youtube tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=wallpaper%20application%20android%20tuts) to develop the wallpaper application. As for storage, you can follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfCiiTEwt3g&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuB_7nB5QD-4bNg6tpdEUImQ) tutorial to store your wallpaper in Firebase which can be enough for the simple application.

Comment: I will follow these tutorials. I am thinking to create two apps, one with firebase storage, and other with google photos api. The one which will be better i'll choose that. Also thank you very much for your great resources. I will update my answer as i'll progress and will achieve what i want in my app.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do so without coding is to go appsgeyser.com and use one of their templates. You can create an wallpaper app for android there and use as many pics as you want.